# Unity: select link

Tags: unity, 22.04, shortcuts

Have "migrated" from **Gnome** to **Unity** (22.04.1),

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop
```

and I must say that after a couple weeks of use Unity appears to be faster and less buggy.

There is something in **Gnome** I used to do to select a `<a>text</a>` link text on a web page: <kbd>Alt</kbd> then select the "anchor" text with the mouse.

It seems to be different in **Unity**.

How to select the text from a link in a web page in **Unity**?